# Is it possible to split a list item into smaller chunks in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which consists of

- `ItemReader<Product>`: reads a product from DB
- `ItemProcesser<Product, List<RelatedProduct>>`: reads related products from the original product
- `ItemWriter<List<RelatedProduct>>`: writes some aspect of related products into DB

Recently, I found a case where a product had so many related products so it caused a long transaction in DB which took about an hour. This happened in our OLTP DB, so we want to split the list of related products into smaller chunks to avoid long transactions.

At first I tried to check the feasibility of code below. But it seemed this kind of code is not possible in Spring Batch.

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .chunk<Product, List<RelatedProduct>>(1)
        .reader(productItemReader())          // reads a product from DB
        .processor(relatedProductProcessor()) // reads related products, the number of related products can be huge.
        // Beginning of my hope
        .reader(eachRelatedProductInListReader()) // reads each related product in the list.
        .chunk(100)                           // re-aggregate them smaller chunks
        // End of my hope
        .writer(relatedProductItemWriter())   // writes info about related products
        .build()
}
```

So now I'm thinking of storing the long list in the job context and adding one more step to process `RelatedProduct` in smaller chunks. But I'm wondering if there are any better ways. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not possible, a chunk-oriented step in Spring Batch can have only one reader. How would solve this data processing requirement without Spring Batch? If you have an algorithm that solves your problem, I can try to help you implement it with Spring Batch.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. I want to prevent a transaction from inserting too many rows. If a product has 10K related products, I want to run 100 transactions that each inserts 100 rows.

Comment: I've just implemented `FlatteningItemReader` which accepts the original item reader and processor. It calls `originalProcessor.process(originalReader.read())` and stores returned `RelatedProduct` values and produces a `RelatedProduct` per `read()` call. But I'm not sure if this is the best approach in Spring Batch.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a new `ItemReader` like below to read `RelatedProduct` one by one using the original reader and processor:

```java
public class FlatteningItemReader<I, O> implements ItemReader<O> {
    private final ItemReader<I> originalReader;
    private final ItemProcessor<I, ? extends Iterable<O>> iterableProducer;
    private final Deque<O> buffer = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public FlatteningItemReader(ItemReader<I> originalReader, ItemProcessor<I, ? extends Iterable<O>> iterableProducer) {
        this.originalReader = Objects.requireNonNull(originalReader);
        this.iterableProducer = Objects.requireNonNull(iterableProducer);
    }

    @Override
    public O read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
            return buffer.pollFirst();
        }
        I item;
        while ((item = originalReader.read()) != null) {
            Iterable<O> iter = iterableProducer.process(item);
            if (iter == null) continue;
            for (O o : iter) {
                buffer.offerLast(o);
            }
            if (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
                return buffer.pollFirst();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The step configuration using `FlatteningItemReader` looks like:

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .chunk<Product, List<RelatedProduct>>(1)
        // reads each RelatedItem using this new reader
        .reader(new FlatteningItemReader(productItemReader(), relatedProductProcessor()))
        .processor(relatedProductProcessor())
        .writer(relatedProductItemWriter())
        .build()
}
```

I'm not sure if this is good approach in Spring Batch.